# How to convert the annotation values of image data into yolo v4 format and upload the images in custom vision

Tags: python, azure, object-detection, microsoft-custom-vision, image-annotations

I tried uploading the image dataset from [Image dataset](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/index.html)with annotation around 500 images . But getting error "Image status : Invalid Region"
[This is the label.txt for single image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGFWx.png)
[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZdcr.jpg) 
I have no idea about how to code this and calculate the annotations value .
I tried different image dataset with annotations from other websites and it is uploaded successfully . Attaching the image and label
[This is the image uploaded successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC4Os.jpg)
[This is the label.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVsaa.png)

can anyone tell me how to calculate the annotation values and upload the images .

Tried with two different dataset with annotations. One dataset is successfully uploaded another dataset annotation values are different and not able to upload.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to normalize the annotation values i.e., should be in range of 0 to 1. You should consider as maximum values the width and height of your images.